# How to set up multiple emulators in xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to do a testing on my iphone application, and I want to know whether it is possible to run multiple emulators at once in XCode?

If yes, how do i go about doing it?

Thank u.

Comment: You cannot even set up *one* emulator. You can setup a simulator, though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make it clear in your question, but I am guessing that what you really want to do here is be able to test on multiple different versions of the OS (iOS 3, iOS 4, iOS 5) in the simulator.

If that's true, take a look under the "Hardware" menu in the iPhone simulator and one of the choices there is "Version".  You can select the OS version you want to simulate with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that. However, in the xcode, how am I able to set up multiple simulators at once? inmstead of just loading one for 1 application.. because I am trying to do performance testing.

Comment: ah, okay... I might withdraw my answer then.  As far as I know, you can not have multiple versions of the same application (including the iPhone Simulator) running on a Macintosh at one time.  What in the world would you be trying to performance test (other than loading down the Macintosh CPU -- which is not really an accurate performance test of an iPhone application)???

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time though! I know you only can do it by switching users, but that's very troublesome to even consider.